# CSS expand element background to fit a container with padding

Tags: html, css

I have a container with padding that includes child's elements.

```css
body {
 margin: 50px;
}

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
 width: 100px;
 border: 1px solid;
 padding: 10px;
}

div:hover {
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div>One</div>
 <div>Two</div>
</section>
```

When I hover on one of the children I want the background to fit the width of the container, how can I do it?

Note that I don't want to add the padding to the children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following way, I applied pseudo element:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 50px;
    }
    
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    section {
        width: 100px;
        border: 1px solid;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    
    div:hover {
        background: red;
        position:relative;
    }
    div::after {
        display:none;
    }
    div:hover::after {
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:-1;
        content:"";
        top:0;
        left:-10px;
        right:-10px;
        bottom:0;
        background-color:red;
    }
    </style>
  
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <div>One</div>
    <div>Two</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why you don't want to add padding to the children.. Because if you just lose the padding on the section and put it on the div, all is solved!

```css
body {
 margin: 50px;
}

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
 width: 100px;
 border: 1px solid;
}

section div {
padding: 10px
}
div:hover {
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div>One</div>
 <div>Two</div>
</section>
```

Comment: because in real life it's more complicated than that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use js and you can't remove the padding from the section, you can use `:before` and `:after`.

```css
section {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

div > span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0;
}

div:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <span>one</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>two</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define section padding just for top and bottom and add padding to divs for right and left you can achieve what you want:

```css
body {
 margin: 50px;
}

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
 width: 100px;
 border: 1px solid;
 padding: 10px 0px;
}

section div {
 padding: 0px 10px;
}

div:hover {
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div>One</div>
 <div>Two</div>
</section>
```